# Incrementation with a for loop

Tags: r, loops

```
x <- c(2,5,4,3,9,8,11,6)
count <- 0
for (val in x) {
  if (val %% 2 == 0) {
    count <- count + 1
  }
} print(count)
# [1] 4
```

I do not get why it is 4 and not 5, could someone give me a hint?

Comment: I believe the numbers that should be true are 2, 4, 8, and 6, nothing more. What other values do you expect? (More specifically, `c(2,5,4,3,9,8,11,6) %% 2` results in `[1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0`.)

Comment: yes indeed, thanks for your help. I was just wondering about the count + 1?

Comment: Unrelated but you can just do `sum(x %%2==0)` or `length(x[x %%2==0] )`. The point is, there is no need for loops in R(in most cases).

Comment: Sari, I don't understand. Your `count <- count + 1` fires only when `%%2` is zero, which happens four times. When complete, it prints out `4`. Do you think it should be incrementing some other time?

Comment: thanks for your help. It's a code from my university, just trying to understand the underlying logic

Comment: 0 + 4 is 4, no?

Comment: thank you r2evans for your help. I think I got it now. I thought it should be 4+1 because of the count "+1"

Comment: Sari, I still don't understand where your confusion is, and I really want to help you with this. Discarding that there are much-more-efficient ways to do this in R, it steps through each value in `x` and increments `count` if that `val`ue is "even" (`val%%2==0`). Since there are four even numbers in that vector, it increments `count` (starting at 0) four times.

Comment: I though "count +1" indicates the output plus 1. But I got it know that it is what the function shall do. So add 1 4 times. Thank you very much for your help - and sorry for bothering with this "easy" question

Answer (score 0):

So from `x <-c(2,5,4,3,9,8,11,6)`, there are only four numbers in which the remainder will be 0 when divided by 2.

Knowing that, let's look at what each part of the code does. You are defining a variable `count` and assigning it the value of 0. Already from the beginning, `count` starts at 0. The next line is a `for` loop. What the loop does is go through each value of `x` (recall that `x <-c(2,5,4,3,9,8,11,6)`). Now, the `if` statement says that for each value of x, if the value is divisible by 2 and has no remainder, add 1 to `count` (which is why you have the line `count <- count + 1`, you are adding 1 to `count`, which started at zero, and reassigning the new value to `count` - think of it as rewriting the value of `count`, replacing it). Now there are four values in x that are divisible by 2 and have a remainder of zero, so doing the math: 0 + 4 = 4. You should get:

```
print(count)
[1] 4
```

Hope this helps explain every aspect of the code. I highly recommend you understand and read about `for` loops, `if` statements, and overall just any R basics. There are several tutorials online explaining all these components.